# v-show alternative for Svelte

Tags: conditional-statements, svelte, svelte-3

The case is that I'm showing `Loading` component on fetch request. I use store to set `$loading` to `true` and inside conditions is the `Loading` component. The problem is that the Loading component seems to be taking some time to show. It feels/looks like the reason is re-rendering of Loading component. So, I was looking for `v-show` like thing in Svelte, which I cannot find in Docs. (Don't get angry if its there, just tell me.)

Can anyone help with this case?

Comment: may be `class:show`?

Comment: Try creating a Loading component using only css with no external assets (no images, videos, lottie, etc) that way the component will show instantly. See https://loading.io/css/ for inspiration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either wrap it in an `{#if someCondition}` block, or slap a `hidden={!someCondition}` attribute on an element.

Comment: Wouldn't wrapping it in an `{ #if }` cause the element to re-render?

Comment: If the value of the condition changes, yes. That's the whole point!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a block of HTML that does not re-render when the condition is changed, here is a simple solution:

```
<script>
  // Show.svelte
  export let show = true;
</script>

<div class:hide={!show}>
  <slot />
</div>

<style>
  .hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>
```

And then use the `Show` component to create that block:

```
<script>
  import Show from "Show.svelte";
  let show = true;
</script>
<button on:click={() => { show = !show}}>
  Click to Show/Hide Content
</button>
<Show {show}>
  <div>Content</div>
</Show>
```

I have posted the `Show` component as an npm package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-show`